# External recordable CCTV, a third black box

Tags: accident-investigation

I wonder if aircraft, and especially large commercial ones, should be fitted with **external recordable CCTV**. This would enable the crew to perform visual pre-flight checks from the cabin that would not normally be possible to ensure that flaps, rudder etc are actually working and to full extent, but also in case of emergency, would enable the crew to visually check the entire aircraft for the same, and for engine fire, for trauma etc at a glance. Valuable time can be wasted trying to figure out what has actually happened. This would also help prevent errors such as shutting down the wrong engine in case of fire. The recordable aspect would also act as an extra "Black box" in case of tragedy  and would no doubt be a great aid to and speed up Crash Investigation.

This system has been employed for many years in the bus and lorry industry, but mainly to help determine blame in case of accident.

Comment: Yes indeed. Safety should always be the number one priority, anything to reinforce safety cannot be dismissed. Perhaps publicity and public opinion might help.

Comment: @Paul It's easy to throw phrases like 'number one priority' around but there's always a compromise. The safest thing to do would be to simply not fly at all - that's the only way to near guarantee not being involved in an air accident. But, you compromise because the risk:reward is worth it.